# Time Dependent Workflow

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Trying to create a time dependent workflow that will take an action (send email to the record owner) when an opportunity record has not been modified in 14 days.  Only condition is the stage is not closed won or lost.  I'm good with queuing the action based on the criteria I described, but struggling with how this action will be removed from the queue when the record is modified prior to the 14 day threshold. As I see it, the most recent update will create a new time trigger action, but the previous queued time trigger needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Time Dependent Actions are automatically removed when the record no longer meets the criteria.  This is mentioned in the documentation. Try it out for yourself; create a record that meets the criteria, check the Monitoring queue, then modify the record so it no longer meets the criteria, and check the queue again-- it will no longer be listed. By the same token, when the user modifies the record (again), it will be re-queued at 14 days again, instead of retaining the previous rule date.